# How do I revert the Player Skin Color after activating 3D Anaglyph?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally activated 3D anaglyph and my character turn black and green.

I've restarted my game, the launcher, and my computer and it doesn't change back. Am I missing a step? How can I get the colours to revert?

Comment: Have you turned the anaglyph back off again?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off 3D anaglyph, and it'll get fixed.